# Powershell Enumerate through all site collections but not include one specific site collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, spsite, windows-server-2008-r2

I am partially not even sure how to Google this question because whatever I type never seems to bring back any relevant search results.

I currently have a working script that is set to go through and change the auditing settings for each site collection.  I am trying to find a way to EXCLUDE one site collection specifically.

Here is my code:

```
$spSites = Get-SpSite -Limit All
oreach ($spSite in $SpSites) {
write-host $spsite
$spsite.TrimAuditLog = $true 
#write-host $spsite.AuditLogTrimmingRetention
$spsite.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 90
$SpSite.Audit.AuditFlags = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Delete -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::update -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::SecurityChange
$SpSite.Audit.Update()
}
```

We have a 1 site collection set up for MySites.  I would like to exclude this site collection but am not sure how to go about doing so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  And as always, thank you in advance!  You guys have been insanely helpful on my sharepoint journey!

Comment: A word of advice, before you test the "exclude" function, comment out the actual update code and replace it with debug code like writing the Url of the site - to confirm it has excluded mysites. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter your logic based on some property of your MySite like this:

```
if ($spsite.Url -ne "http://mysite.domain.com") {
   ... audit code ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, Dave! Ill give this a shot tomorrow when I am back in the office.

Comment: Forgot to flag this one as the solution I went with.  Worked like a charm, thanks for helping out a powershell green pea!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a filter while retrieving the Site collection list from Get-SPSite:

```
$spsites = Get-SPSite -Filter { $_.Url -ne "http://mysite.com" }
```

The Filter parameter is described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx).