# Using Get-SPSite -Filter

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, spsite

I seem to be having some trouble using the `Filter` parameter on the `Get-SPSite` cmdlet.

Using [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60002/powershell-enumerate-through-all-site-collections-but-not-include-one-specific-s) question for reference, I'd hoped to filter out the Site that I was getting, to later on exclude it from being moved outside the Content DB.

I'm getting an error on the line;

```
Get-SPSite -Filter {$_.Url -ne "http://mysites.dev.local/"} -ContentDatabase "WSS_Content_MySites" -Limit 1
```

The error being:

**Get-SPSite : Not a valid filter string format. The format is (property) (operator) (value).**

I don't seem to be doing anything differently from the aforementioned question. Could anyone help?

**Answer Edit:**

From [this](https://jimecox.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/powershell-sharepoint-2010-learning-area-2/) blog, I found this little gem:

***The filter parameter support is as follows:***

a. SPWeb supports: Title and Template

b. SPSite and SPSiteAdministration supports: Owner, SecondaryContact, and LockState

It seems the `-Filter` parameter is very limited in what it can provide, and thus in this instance, was necessary to use a `Where-Object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [**Get-SPSite** documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx):

> The Filter parameter is a server-side filter **for certain site
>   collection properties** that are stored in the content database; without
>   the Filter parameter, filtering on these properties is a slow process.
>   **These site collection properties are Owner, SecondaryOwner, and
>   LockState**. The Filter parameter is a script block that uses the same
>   syntax as a Where-Object statement, but is run on the server for
>   faster results.

I think it's stated *we can't filter by anything* except `Owner, SecondaryOwner, LockState` in `Get-SPSite -filter`. Matches my experiments. Let's see [documentation on **Get-SPWeb**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx):

> The Filter parameter is a server-side filter **for certain subsite
>   properties** that are stored in the content database; without the Filter
>   parameter, filtering on these properties is a slow process. These
>   subsite properties are **Template and Title**. The Filter parameter is a
>   script block that uses the same syntax as a Where-Object statement,
>   but is run server-side for faster results.

I read it like this: *we can't filter by anything* except `Template, Title` in `Get-SPWeb -filter`.

---

So

`Get-SPSite -Filter {$_.Url -ne "http://mysites.dev.local"}`

will not work and should be replace with semantically equivalent

`Get-SPSite | ? {$_.Url -ne "http://mysites.dev.local"}`

Comment: I'm having to use `-Limit 1` as this portion of code is part of a greater loop that moves sites one-by-one. Using your above example is only getting me the host site (the one I wished to exclude), with the host name/port number etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If sites are fetched one by one, why not use site url as `-Identity` on each loop?

Comment: Because I'm not fetching the sites by identity, they're being served from the DB effectively randomly. However, there's one that needs to be excluded

Comment: Would you try without trailing `/` in URL?

Comment: Reading over your edit, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use | Where, for example:

```
Get-SPSite | where{$_.Url.Startswith("http://intranet....")}
```

Comment: Well, you are not using the `-Filter` parameter, which is what this question concerns